# How to share image from my app on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I want to allow users to share image from my app on Facebook. Say I already have an image (i.e. file path). How do I go about letting a user share it on Facebook? Basically I want the user to agree once. Then from there on, whenever the user takes a certain action in my app, share a particular image on Facebook on behave of the user. Notice that the image is to be shared automatically without the user having to take action each time; so the Facebook sharing is incidental to some other action in my app. I am looking at the Facebook documentations. It is not clear which path to take to accomplish what I need. So thanks for any guidance.

Again, the user agrees once and goes on her merry way. Then the app, each time a user takes a certain action, share an image on Facebook.

**UPDATE**

Here is the [path I have identified for sharing a photo on behalf of a user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/open-graph)

1. Setting up your app to use Open Graph
2. Creating an Open Graph Story
3. Posting with API calls

The problem with this approach is that, at least in the sample project, the user has to click on `Share` each time. But I don't want the user to have to click on share each time. I want them to give me permission once. And then from there the app shares for them automatically.

Trial and error is expensive here as it is a lot to implement just to see if it were what I was looking to do: Which is why I am asking here, hoping someone here has done this in the past and don't mind sharing their experience.

Comment: There are different ways to do this. Do you want to do it via Facebook API only ? Or are you open to other (faster) means ?

Comment: @ZygoteInit I am open to any means. As long as the user only grants access once. And the user does not need to already have the Facebook app installed on her/his device to use my app. Also the user should not have to approve each post each time: it has to be a one time access only; so the feature does not become an annoyance.

Comment: to do what you want is then only possible using Facebook API :/

Comment: I tried looking for a tutorial for you, but it seems there isn't a good one ... not one that makes use of the latest API anyway. I had used the [socialauth](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/) library in the past to do this, but that one seems deprecated now.

Comment: the way i had initially thought of makes use of the Android framework itself ... but that will force the user to choose the app every time, and it needs the native FB app to be installed on the device :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ask the user for the `publish_actions` permission, and then use `Request.newUploadPhotoRequest` to publish a photo. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Request/#newUploadPhotoRequest

Comment: Would that be part of the pathway I have identified above (i.e. as step 4 in the `Custom Story` or is that a different pathway altogether?  As a newbie to Facebook Api, it is not clear to me what is upstream of your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: For example, Facebook has a thing about submitting explicit action for approval. So would this be considered an explicit action (if you know, of course)?

Comment: If you use the uploadPhotoRequest, you don't need to create a custom story at all. It will just post a photo to the user's timeline.

Comment: wow! Awesome! I will look into that. It sounds like it may be just what I needed. Thanks. I start looking into implementing it. Thanks.

Comment: I think I find a problem. That call seems to permanently add a photo to a user's photo album as opposed to simply sharing it in the news feed of user and friends. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. Even if you use custom stories you still put a photo in the user's album if you upload a picture with your action. The other method is to store your photos elsewhere (if your app has a server side and website), and then just do a link share.

Comment: I am still struggling to get it to work. Do you happen to have an example by any chance? Perhaps a complete working example that includes the `publish_actions` portion as well.

Comment: Have a look at the HelloFacebook sample that ships with the SDK. It shows both how to ask for publish_actions as well as using the uploadPhotoRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You need uses-permission Facebook, try this; https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

After you do this, you need to take method onClick and send the picture directly for facebook, but for this, is necessary the login of user's.